# beautifulsoup: get text (including html tags) between two different tags (</h3> and <h2>)

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape an html file structured as follow using beautifulsoup. Basicaly, each unit is constisted of:

- one `<h2></h2>`
- one `<h3></h3>`
- more than one `<p></p>`

Something like follow:

```
<h2>January, 2020</h2>
<h3>facility</h3>
<p>text1-1</p>
<p>text1-2</p>

<h2>April, 2020</h2>
<h3>scientists</h3>
<p>text2-1</p>
<p>text2-2</p>

<h2>June, 2020</h2>
<h3>lawyers</h3>
<p>text3-1</p>

<h2>.....
```

I want to get text including the `<p>` tags between `</h3>` and the next `<h2>`. The result should be:

for row #1:

```
<p>text1-1</p>
<p>text1-2</p>
```

for row #2:

```
<p>text2-1</p>
<p>text2-2</p>
```

for row #3:

```
<p>text3-1</p>
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
num_h2 = len(soup.find_all('h2'))

for i in range(0,num_h2):
    print('---------')
    print(i) 

    p_string = ''
    sibling = soup.find_all('h3')[i].find_next_sibling('p').getText()

    if sibling:
        p_string += sibling
    else:
        break

    print(p_string)
```

The problem with this solution is that it only shows the content of the first `<p>` under each unit. I do not know how to find how many `<p>` are there to generate a for loop. Also, is there a better way to do this than using `find_next_silibing()`?

Comment: Sure there's a way. Any attempts on your side?

Comment: @baduker thanks. I updated my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe css selectors can help:

```
for s in soup.select('h3'):
    for ns in (s.fetchNextSiblings()):        
        if ns.name == "h2":
            break
        else:
            if ns.name == "p":
                print(ns)
```

Output:

```
<p>text1-1</p>
<p>text1-2</p>
<p>text2-1</p>
<p>text2-2</p>
<p>text3-1</p>
```